# how to remove a parent in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database. The user is deleted automatically when the user destroys the application. What I want is for the parent group ("مجموعة") to be deleted when all users are deleted.

[image: Firebase database]

I have tried this code but it doesn't work

[image: code]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use in this case a Firebase Cloud function to automaticaly delete the parent data if all users are delete. The cloud function would look something like this:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.handleDelete = functions.database
  .ref("/groups/{groupID}/users/{userID}")
  .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
    const { groupID } = context.params;

    //Handle delete
    //Check if there are other users and if not remove the whole parent data

    const usersSnap = await admin
      .database()
      .ref(`/groups/${groupID}/users`)
      .get();

    if (!usersSnap.exists()) {
      //Delete the parent daat
      await admin.database().ref(`/groups/${groupID}`).set(null);
    }

    return;
  });
```